# 404 Not found Page in Django when deploy with docker and cookiecutter

Tags: django, web-deployment, traefik

I'm having a weird problem when deploying to the production of Django.
Previously when accessing https://gae-gw.systems. I work very normally, but today when I try to access again all 404 errors.
Currently, I use Traefik as a proxy server.
Consider the following configs:

Traefik.yml

```
entryPoints:
  web:
    # http
    address: ":80"
    http:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#entrypoint
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: web-secure

  web-secure:
    # https
    address: ":443"


certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#lets-encrypt
    acme:
      email: "khoadautay@gmail.com"
      storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#httpchallenge
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web

http:
  routers:
    web-secure-router:
      rule: "Host(`gae-gw.systems`) || Host(`www.gae-gw.systems`)"
      entryPoints:
        - web-secure
      middlewares:
        - csrf
      service: django
      tls:
        # https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/routers/#certresolver
        certResolver: letsencrypt

  middlewares:
    csrf:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/middlewares/headers/#hostsproxyheaders
      # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax
      headers:
        accessControlAllowOriginList: "*"
        hostsProxyHeaders: ["X-CSRFToken"]

  services:
    django:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://django:5000
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", index, name="index"),
    path("home/", HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
    path("users/", include("erp_greenwich.users.urls", namespace="users")),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```